# deleting a row in integration of jsf spring hibernate primefaces

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i am using integration of jsf hibernate spring primfaces in my project. i want to delete row in my primefaces data table. but i am not sure about delete method in my managed bean. when i want to delete i have following error. please help me to write correct deletePersonel method.

```
/personel.xhtml @95,74 actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel()}": java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Personel.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBLPERSONEL")
public class Personel {
@Id
@Column(name="PERSONEL_ID")
private int personel_id;
@Column(name="PNAME")
private String pname;
@Column(name="PFAMILY")
private String pfamily;
@Column(name="PADDRESS")
private String paddress;
@Column(name="PPHONE")
private String pphone;
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Manager manager;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="personel")
private Set<Stufftransfer> stufftransfers;
public Personel(){

}
//getter and setter
```

PersonelDao

```
public class PersonelDao implements IPersonelDao {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
public void deletePersonel(Personel personel) {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(personel);

}
```

PersonelService

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class PersonelService implements IPersonelService{
    IPersonelDao personeldao;

    public IPersonelDao getPersoneldao() {
        return personeldao;
    }

    public void setPersoneldao(IPersonelDao personeldao) {
        this.personeldao = personeldao;
    }
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
    @Override
    public void deletePersonel(Personel personel) {
        getPersoneldao().deletePersonel(personel);

    }
```

PersonelBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="personelMB")
@SessionScoped
public class PersonelBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{PersonelService}")
    IPersonelService personelservice;
    List<Personel> personelList;

    private int personel_id;
    private String pname;
    private String pfamily;
    private String paddress;
    private String pphone;
public IPersonelService getPersonelservice() {
        return personelservice;
    }
    public void setPersonelservice(IPersonelService personelservice) {
        this.personelservice = personelservice;
    }
    public List<Personel> getPersonelList() {
        personelList=new ArrayList<Personel>();
        personelList.addAll(getPersonelservice().getPersonels());
        return personelList;
    }
    public void setPersonelList(List<Personel> personelList) {
        this.personelList = personelList;
    }
public void addPersonel(){
        Personel personel=new Personel();
        personel.setPaddress(getPaddress());
        personel.setPersonel_id(getPersonel_id());
        personel.setPfamily(getPfamily());
        personel.setPname(getPname());
        personel.setPphone(getPphone());
        getPersonelservice().addPersonel(personel);
    }
    public void deletePersonel(){
        Personel personel=(Personel)personelservice.getPersonelId(personel_id);
getPersonelservice().deletePersonel(personel);
    }
//getter and setter
```

personel.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="rtl" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
>
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>اطلاعات پرسنلی</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h1>اضافه کردن پرسنل جدید</h1>
        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid columns="4" >
              شماره پرسنلی : 
                <h:inputText id="id" value="#{personelMB.personel_id}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="id" >
                </h:inputText>
                <br></br>
                نام : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{personelMB.pname}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="Name" >
                </h:inputText>

                 نام خانوادگی: 
                <h:inputText id="family" value="#{personelMB.pfamily}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="family" >
                </h:inputText> 

                آدرس : 
                <h:inputTextarea id="address" value="#{personelMB.paddress}" 
                    cols="30" rows="10" required="true"
                    label="Address" >
                </h:inputTextarea>


          تلفن:  
                <h:inputText id="tel" value="#{personelMB.pphone}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="tel" >
                </h:inputText> 
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="درج اطلاعات" action="#{personelMB.addPersonel()}" />

        </h:form>
 <h2>مشاهده اطلاعات پرسنل</h2>  
 <h:form prependId="false">  

    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="personel" value="#{personelMB.personelList}" rowKey="#{personelMB.personel_id}">  

        <f:facet name="header">  
            اطلاعات پرسنل 
        </f:facet>  

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
               شماره پرسنلی  
            </f:facet>  

            <h:outputText value="#{personel.personel_id}" />  

            <f:facet name="footer">  
                کدملی 
            </f:facet>  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="نام">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pname}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="نام خانوادگی">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pfamily}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="آدرس">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.paddress}" />  
        </p:column>  
   <p:column headerText="تلفن">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pphone}" />  
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
      <f:facet name="حذف">
         <h:outputText value="" />
      </f:facet>
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="حذف"
                       actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel()}" />
   </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">  
            تعداد رکورد#{fn:length(personelMB.getPersonelList())} میباشد.  
        </f:facet>  

    </p:dataTable>  

</h:form>  

</h:body>
</html>
```

please help me to write correct deletePersonel in my PersonelBean.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your managed bean delete method likes this;

```
   public void deletePersonel(int personel_id){
       Personel personel=(Personel)personelservice.getPersonelId(personel_id);
       getPersonelservice().deletePersonel(personel);
   }
```

and also change your xhtml likes this;

```
  <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="حذف"
                   actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel(personel.personel_id)}" />
```

Add refresh method to your managed bean likes this;

```
 public String deleteAction(Personel personel) {
    personelList.remove(personel);
    return null;
  }
```

and edit your p:commandButton likes this;

```
  <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="حذف"
                   actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel(personel.personel_id)" action="#{personelMB.delectAction(personel)}"/>
```

Comment: thanks alot, would you please tell me how to refresh datatable after deleting?

Comment: i have this error:/personel.xhtml @96,139 action="#{personelMB.deleteAction(personel)}": Method not found: managedbean.PersonelBean@4487c2f5.deleteAction(model.Personel)

Comment: @sami download and add jboss el jar then also fill this<context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
  <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param> in web.xml

Comment: dear Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye,thanks for your pay attention. i add the jar file. i have no error but the data table does not refresh after deleting a row.

Comment: i find the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829378/pdatatable-refresh-datatable-after-delete-row/11840939#11840939