# p:dataTable - refresh datatable after delete row

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

following is my data table pic and i want when i delete a row, data table refreshes. but row deleted from DB but doesnot delete from data table after that.
[image]
i try following codes but they could not help me.

```
<h2>مشاهده اطلاعات پرسنل</h2>   
 <h:form id="f2" prependId="false">  

    <p:dataTable id="pdataTable" var="personel" value="#{personelMB.personelList}" rowKey="#{personelMB.personel_id}"
    >  

        <f:facet name="header">  
            اطلاعات پرسنل 
        </f:facet>  

        <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
               شماره پرسنلی  
            </f:facet>  

            <h:outputText value="#{personel.personel_id}" />  

            <f:facet name="footer">  
                کدملی 
            </f:facet>  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="نام">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pname}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="نام خانوادگی">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pfamily}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="آدرس">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.paddress}" />  
        </p:column>  
   <p:column headerText="تلفن">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pphone}" />  
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
      <f:facet name="حذف">
         <h:outputText value="" />
      </f:facet>
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="حذف"
                       actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel(personel.personel_id)}" update="pdataTable"/>
   </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">  
            تعداد رکورد#{fn:length(personelMB.getPersonelList())} میباشد.  
        </f:facet>  

    </p:dataTable>  

</h:form>
```

2.second try:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="حذف"
 actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel(personel.personel_id)}" reRender="pdataTable"/>
                   </p:column>
```

3.third try:
personelBean.java

```
public void deletePersonel(int personel_id){
        Personel personel=(Personel)personelservice.getPersonelId(personel_id);
        getPersonelservice().deletePersonel(personel);
    }
    public String deleteAction(Personel personel) {
        personelList.remove(personel);
        return null;
      }
```

xhtml file

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="حذف"
                       actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel(personel.personel_id)}" action="#{personelMB.deleteAction(personel)}"/>
   </p:column>
```

please help me.

Comment: Check that your bean is ViewScoped.

Comment: i was used @SessionScoped. i changed it to ViewScoped but it did not work too.

Comment: Are you sure the action method is running? I mean, have you debugged or post log traces to see that effectively the method has been executed? It could be a Java problem instead of JSF/Primefaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of ajax to be false made it true.

```
actionListener="#{personelMB.deletePersonel(personel.personel_id)}"  update="@form" ajax="true"/>
```

Comment: `ajax="true"` is the default, so this answer is **not** correct in that regard. The real problem was that the `reRender` should be changed to `update`. So the community change made the answer worse...

Answer (score 0):

use update="@form" parameter on commandbutton

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried like this in

```
 <p:commandButton update=":f2:pdataTable"></p:commandButton>
```